# Ag-grid how do i set default parameters for exportDataAsExcel

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

So in React + Aggrid i can choose to export an excel document with specific parameters via a button like so:

```js
onClick={() => gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({columnGroups: true, fileName: 'name_of_file' })}
```

How do i get these parameters to become default? So that when right-clicking, the same parameters will apply.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `defaultExportParams` which are the params used for the export when exporting via right click.

See [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/react/export/) for the list of available properties for `defaultExportParams`.

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/mlFpiexLZpyqyYf8).

Comment: YES! That is exactly what i was looking for. And very well explained, much better than the documentation.
Neither [export](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/react/export/) nor [excel-export](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/react/excel-export/)  contains the word "defaultExportParams". Thank you!